# Error: "the focus is undefined"

Tags: xslt, qtxml

I use this xslt (FpML is the root of my document):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="/FpML"/> 
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

within this code:

```
if(schema.isValid())
{
    QXmlSchemaValidator validator(schema);
    QByteArray data(this->xmlTextEdit->toPlainText().toStdString().c_str());
    QBuffer buffer(&data);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    if (validator.validate(&buffer))
        qDebug() << "instance document is valid";
    else
        qDebug() << "instance document is invalid";

    QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
     query.setFocus(&buffer);
     qDebug() << QDir::current();

     QUrl XSLT("test__.xslt");
     if( XSLT.isValid())
     {
        query.setQuery(XSLT);

         QString result;
         query.evaluateTo(&result);
         this->xslTextEdit->setPlainText(result);
     }
}
```

And i got this error:

```
at line 10, column 18: The focus is undefined
```

when googling I found this:

> If the function is a user-defined function, the converted argument values are bound to the
>     formal parameters of the function, and the function body is evaluated. The value returned by
>     the function body is then converted to the declared return type of the function by applying the 
>     function conversion rules.
>
> A function does not inherit a focus (context item, context position, and context size) from the 
>     environment of the function call. During evaluation of a function body, the focus is undefined, 
>     except where it is defined by the action of some expression inside the function body. Use of an 
>     expression that depends on the focus when the focus is undefined results in a dynamic error.

But I'm not sure I understand. Is the problem really in my stylesheet ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the buffer passed to the focus, apprently it was silently colsed, after schema validation. I added an extra "open"

```
if(schema.isValid())
{
    QXmlSchemaValidator validator(schema);
    QByteArray data(this->xmlTextEdit->toPlainText().toStdString().c_str());
    QBuffer buffer(&data);
    buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    if (validator.validate(&buffer))
        qDebug() << "instance document is valid";
    else
        qDebug() << "instance document is invalid";

    QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);

     qDebug() << QDir::current();

     QUrl XSLT("test__.xslt");
     if( XSLT.isValid())
     {
        buffer.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        query.setFocus(&buffer);
        query.setQuery(XSLT);

         QString result;
         query.evaluateTo(&result);
         this->xslTextEdit->setPlainText(result);
     }
}
```